# how can I add the count value in a cal-heatmap

Tags: javascript, cal-heatmap

I want to display the 'count' value instead of the date in a calendar

e.g this represents a heatmap of the month of July but instead of the day (1-31) I want to output the number of occurences (count of items)

[code playground](https://liveweave.com/JelL9C)
[image]

I am using the package [cal-heatmap.](https://cal-heatmap.com/#subDomainTextFormat) 
I added this property:

```
subDomainTitleFormat: {
                         filled: 'count'
                     },
```

but it doesn't change the value displayed in the month

Answer (score 0):

You have to use it as filled: '{count}' and it will work. 'count' refers to a simple string and not a variable . Check out this [edited code](https://liveweave.com/88kQBw)